# Install ArgoCD using terraform

Tags: terraform, devops, argocd

How to install ArgoCD in my kubernetes cluster using terraform? How to do it using "best practices"?

ChatGPT recommends for me next steps:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  config_path = "~/.kube/config"
}

resource "kubectl_manifest" "argocd_install" {
  yaml_body = file("${path.module}/install.yaml")  # path to file install.yaml, that you downloaded
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take at look at this article for best practices for installing ArgoCD using terraform instead of using chatGPT.

- Medium-article [Visit](https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-set-up-argo-cd-with-terraform-to-implement-pure-gitops-d5a1d797926a)
- Manage Kubernetes Cluster with Terraform and Argo CD [Link](https://piotrminkowski.com/2022/06/28/manage-kubernetes-cluster-with-terraform-and-argo-cd/)